# I replaced the faucet in the kitchen and my water won’t come back out

Tags: kitchen-sink

I recently had a hose tear in my sink faucet, so I replaced the whole thing. I got it all hooked up and now the water won’t come out. I even took the connector off and turned the water back on and nothing came out of the pipe either. Could this be debris or is something else wrong?  I have water in other rooms, just not my kitchen sink

---

[image]

It’s mostly all new. The previous owner looks like he replaced most of the house

Comment: Welcome. You'd want to revise to tell us more about the plumbing. Otherwise we're left throwing darts in the dark. Please update your question with a detailed description of the scenario and/or post photos.

Comment: I have had valves plug up down stream from work I was doing but your shut off valves should be before the hoses to the faucet, are the valves really old?  I have had gate valves break so they closed but when you tried to open them the gate was stuck shut this happened with valves that were close to 50 years old.

Comment: I’ll stab in the dark: it’s possible there is a second cutoff valve you forgot to open

Comment: I can't quite tell from the photo,  but be warned - if that is plastic pipe connecting the feed to the upper flex hoses, the hot water side is very likely to fall apart within months, leading to a flood.  Get  quick-connect, metal-jacketed, hoses instead.